# Android onTouch returning wrong color

Tags: android, image, touch-event

I have a strange problem getting the color of the point that was touched. I created an image (.bmp) and filled it with the paint can. No gradients or other colors. Most of the time when I touch the screen, I get the color I am expecting, but sometimes I get a slightly different color. My code seems straightforward enough:

```
 final Bitmap bm2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_overlay);
 if (bm2!=null) {
    overlayimage.setImageBitmap(bm2);
    image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent mev) {
            Log.d(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "onTouch()");
            DecodeActionDownEvent(v, mev, bm2);
            return false;
        }
    });
 }


 private void DecodeActionDownEvent(View v, MotionEvent ev, Bitmap bm2)
 {
    Log.d(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "DecodeActionDownEvent()");
    xCoord = new Integer((int)ev.getRawX());
    yCoord = new Integer((int)ev.getRawY());
    colorTouched = bm2.getPixel(xCoord, yCoord);
    Log.d(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "The coordinates touched were x: " + xCoord + "; y: " + yCoord);
    Log.d(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "The color touched was (hex) " + Integer.toHexString(colorTouched));
 }
```

Recently I got a "miss", and checked the coordinates of the image by moving the eyedropper tool around until it was on the exact spot, and the pixel there is no different than the other pixels in the area.

Is it not "safe" to expect android to return the exact color? If I paint a target with #ff424542, is it not safe to assume that if I hit that target, I would get a pixel color of #ff424542? In this case, android was returning #ff4a454a. The attached image is my "image_overlay" file. The area I am targeting is the dark gray in the middle-right. Like I said, most of the time it works perfectly, but every once in a while I record a miss, even when I am clearly in the target zone. From my logs, recent misses were at x: 360, y:399 and x:368, y:399. Successful hits were at x:363, y:393 and x:365, y434.

[image: image_overlay]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using the eyedropper tool in an app on your PC, where you generated the image?  You are then assuming that the image you are working with in Android is identical to the one you are working with on your PC.  However, this is not a safe assumption.  What are the properties of your source bitmap, e.g. resolution, DPI etc.  Then take a look at Bitmap.decodeFile.    The clue is in "decode".  By default (hence the question about the bitmap properties), Android will not simply read the bitmap from your file specifier and load it into memory.  For example, and I'm not sure without digging into the source code, perhaps decodeFile is dithering the resultant bitmap.

You should be using BitmapFactoryOptions to control how the input bitmap is decoded:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html

Comment: I was actually wondering if something like that was going on. I suspect you are correct. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You're welcome, hope it works for you.  If it does, please do come back and accept the answer.  Cheers